# CoreOS linux ignition.json, download a remote directory, is it possible?

Tags: coreos, coreos-ignition

I am newbie to Flatcar Linux. I managed to install flatcar linux to disk successfully.Is it possible to download a remote directory using `ignition.json`  ?

I have a very minimal `ignition.json`. Partial snippet is here

```
 "storage": {
  "files": [{
    "filesystem": "root",
    "path": "/etc/hostname",
    "mode": 420,
    "contents": { "source": "data:,core4" }
  },
  {
    "filesystem": "root",
    "path": "/opt/bin/mydata",
    "user": {},
    "contents": {
        "source": "http://192.168.56.114/ks/mydata",
        "verification": {}
    },
```

But this creates a blank directory in `/opt/bin` named `mydata`.

Is it possible to Download a remote directory?

Regards,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the current version of Ignition configuration specification (`v3.3.0`) does not support that.

To check what is currently supported, you can look at the current specification at https://coreos.github.io/ignition/configuration-v3_3/.